xsane can't find network scanner unless given on command line
I have a scanner connected to a server on my local network. Scanning locally on the server with scanimage works fine. Scanning remotely only works when I explicitly provide the address net:myhostname:devicepath on the command line, but otherwise xsane claims no devices found although the net sane dll is enabled. Any help dealing with this is most welcome!
